# How to copy on array to another array in different ways - Pascal

Tags: arrays, pascal

I'm solving 3 problems with array.The two of them I've already solved and I 've got 2 questions.

If the codes for the first two are good and how to solve the third problem.

Okay,the third problem is to copy array to another array this way: arrayA=[1,2,3], then arrayB is [1,2,3,3,2,1].

Firstly from start to end and then from end to start.First problem was to copy arrayA to arrayB in this way: arrayA=[1,2,3] ,arrayB=[1,1,2,2,3,3]. 
I will only post my pseudocodes.

```
while i<length(a) do begin
  b[j]=a[i];
  j+=1;
  if (j+1) MOD 2 =0 then i+=1;
end;
```

Another one was to copy arrayA to arrayB twice.arrayA=[1,2,3], arrayB=[1,2,3,1,2,3]. Here I used for loop:

```
for i=1 to length(a) do arrayB[i]=arrayA[i];
for i=length(a)+1 to 2*length(a) do arrayB[i]=arrayA[i-length(a)]
```

Comment: Your description is hard to follow, but the big problem is that your examples are not complete. Depending on the type of array, bounds can vary in Pascal, so what you show is not enough to answer any questions. Oh, and enable all checking (range, overflow, arithmetic), -CRriot if you use Free Pascal.

Comment: It's array allocated by me ,NOT dynamically ,so index starts at 1 ...I dont get it,how can CRiot help me?

Comment: That's the problem, @Hasin. You haven't posted you allocation code and people just can't guess how was it. I'd suggest you to post more of your code if you want to obtain more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `while` cycles if count is predefined.
Exploit simple index arithmetics (I assume that all arrays are 1-based):

```
//112233
for i := 1 to length(a) do begin
  b[2 * i - 1] := a[i];
  b[2 * i] := a[i];
end;

//123123
l := length(a);
for i := 1 to length(a) do begin
  b[i] := a[i];
  b[i + l] := a[i];
end;

//123321
l := length(a);
for i := 1 to length(a) do begin
  b[i] := a[i];
  b[2*l - i + 1] := a[i];
end;
```